# DataInputStream readByte blocked / hanging

Tags: java, sockets

I'm looking at the code for a server that creates a thread to handle each incoming connection.  The problem is that for some reason on a bunch of threads, the DataInputStream created from the socket is hanging on readByte and not throwing any exceptions.  The timeout is set for 60 seconds, so I'm not sure what the next step is with this.

```
socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
socketInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
byte connectionOptions = socketDataInputStream.readByte();
```

Comment: You're sure there's a byte to read? Does `available()` return greater than 0?

Comment: @mohamed how do you mean?  I am pretty sure that a socket is only handled by 1 thread, and its just sitting there on readByte waiting forever (no timeout).

Answer (score 2):

You indicated in a comment that you're waiting for a `SocketException`. If so you need to catch `SocketTimeoutException` instead. For example, this code will output `timeout!` if you telnet to port 3434 and wait 3 seconds:

```
try {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3434);
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
    InputStream socketInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socketInputStream);
    dataInputStream.readByte();
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println("timeout!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the full thread dump for deadlock.
 
`ctrl + break` for windows.
`ctrl + |` or `kill -3 PID` for linux.

or Use `jvisualvm` or `jconsole` tools.

`timeout` value should be in milliseconds.

Comment: I believe the OP is expecting the SoTimeout to trigger a SocketException after the timeout is reached.

Comment: Yes, with jconsole, I see the threads just sitting there on the third line @ readByte - but as Peter said, I'm waiting for the SocketException and its not happening